# Get error when running php bin/magento setup:di:compile

Tags: magento2, error, upgrade

After firing this command in command line php bin/magento setup:di:compile I am getting this error:

> Cannot declare interface Magento\Framework\App\DeploymentConfig\Writer\FormatterInterface, because the name is already in use in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/DeploymentConfig/Writer/FormatterInterface.php on line 9

Can you have a best solution for me?

Thanks

Comment: Is there any custom extension?

Comment: just try with remove var folder from root and run again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try to remove all the directories inside var/generation folder and then run following command :

> php bin/magento cache:flush

After that run your command you will be succeed.

Comment: Thank for your idea!

Comment: Most welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that in your interface and also the interface that Magento says you are re-declaring, that you have declared the namespace at the top of both classes. This has happened to me before and that is usually the reason.